# Перекрытие методов в классе

Tags: c++

```
struct A
{
        void f(int);
};
struct B : A
{
        void f(long);
};

B b;
b.f(1);
```

Почему void f(long) перекрыл void f(int)? Я думал, что прототип функции производного класса должен полностью соответствовать прототипу функции базового, то есть для перекрытая этой функции нужно не только одинаковое имя самой функции, а и тоже самое количество и тип параметров. Почему тогда в данном коде не overloading, а override?

Comment: @mzarb, Вы бы лучше подумали о других программистах, которым придется читать подобный код (с одинаковыми именами).

IMHO если есть возможность, то лучше стремиться к тому, что бы **имена были разные**. Не стоит увлекаться переопределением функций, typedef-ами, выбрасыванием из деклараций ключевого слова `struct` и т.п., а также передачей параметров по ссылке (вместо этого передайте просто адрес) и излишне обобщенным программированием.

Я понимаю, что некоторые подобные штуки приятны при написании и выглядят элегантно, но часто затрудняют понимание кода другими людьми.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Так устроен с++. Это на первых порах вводит всех в ступор. Нужно понимать, как происходит поиск подходящей функции. Вначале просмартивается класс на наличие подходящих функций. И только если они не находятся, начинается просмотр функций родителя. так как `1` можно без проблем преобразовать в long, то и будет вызвана функция `void f(long);`

Если интересны детали, читайте в стандарте в пункте 13.2 (Declaration matching).

Comment: А почему тогда с `void f(long, int)` не скомпилируется, ведь в `B` есть метод `void f(int)` из `A` ?

Comment: поиск происходит по имени, а не сигнатуре. Поэтому, просмотрев список функций с именем `f`, он находит только ` void f(long, int)`. А потом понимает, что оно не подходит. А к предкам уже не идет. Почему? так задумано. Вот если бы у класса `B` не было функций с именем `f`, тогда поиск кандидатов пошел бы к предку. В целом - пункт 13.3.